# How to make this Twisted Python Proxy faster?

Tags: python, http, proxy, twisted

The code below is an HTTP proxy for content filtering. It uses GET to send the URL of the current site to the server, where it processes it and responds. It runs **VERY**, **VERY**, **VERY** slow. Any ideas on how to make it faster?

**Here is the code:**

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import http
from twisted.web.proxy import Proxy, ProxyRequest
from Tkinter import *
#import win32api
import urllib2
import urllib
import os
import webbrowser

cwd = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])[0]
proxies = {}
user = "zachb"
class BlockingProxyRequest(ProxyRequest):
    def process(self):
        params = {}
        params['Location']= self.uri
        params['User'] = user
        params = urllib.urlencode(params)
        req = urllib.urlopen("http://weblock.zbrowntechnology.info/ProgFiles/stats.php?%s" % params, proxies=proxies)
        resp = req.read()
        req.close()
        if resp == "allow":
            pass
        else:
            self.transport.write('''BLOCKED BY ADMIN!''')
            self.transport.loseConnection()

        ProxyRequest.process(self)

class BlockingProxy(Proxy):
    requestFactory = BlockingProxyRequest
factory = http.HTTPFactory()
factory.protocol = BlockingProxy

reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this run faster? Or even a better way to write it?

Comment: I'm sorry, it sounds like you're just saying that the server is slow to respond.  What am i missing?

Comment: Yes, I am. It runs VERY, VERY, VERY slow. I'm trying to figure out a way to make it run faster. I've been Googling, but nothing so far. I figured I'd post it here to see if anyone else knew a better way. I would write it using other libraries or modules, but Twisted is the only one I could find docs and examples on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main cause of slowness in this proxy is probably these three lines:

```
    req = urllib.urlopen("http://weblock.zbrowntechnology.info/ProgFiles/stats.php?%s" % params, proxies=proxies)
    resp = req.read()
    req.close()
```

A normal Twisted-based application is single threaded.  You have to go out of your way to get threads involved.  That means that whenever a request comes in, you are blocking the one and only processing thread on this HTTP request.  No further requests are processed until this HTTP request completes.

Try using one of the APIs in twisted.web.client, (eg [Agent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) or [getPage](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html)).  These APIs don't block, so your server will handle concurrent requests concurrently.  This should translate into much smaller response times.

Comment: +1 - Scrolled down to look at the answers with those three lines on my clipboard. I'll go make myself a cup of tea instead.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but how did you come to this conclusion? When I make the request from the Python command line, it takes maybe a millisecond.... why would this be the problem?

Comment: It's just a guess, since you didn't say what "VERY, VERY, VERY slow" actually means (in objective terms, like requests/second), and you didn't say what load you're applying to the server.  I made this guess rather than another because of Twisted's single-threaded operation.  From my network, it takes about 53 milliseconds.  That means that if I ran this proxy, the most requests/second it could ever handle would be 1000 / 53 == 18.8.  And that's before we count the other costs of handling the request (which are small, but non-zero).

Comment: Wow, so you think I just need to find another way to write this blocking proxy, without Twisted?

Comment: No, I think you need to find another way to write this Twisted proxy, without blocking. ;)  I suggested Agent and getPage as replacements for urllib.  If you try that and it's still too slow, then it'll be time to look for another cause. :)

Comment: But, the point of using the proxy if for blocking. It has to block. I'll check in to Agent and getPage.

Comment: You're talking about "blocking" as in "restricting access to content".  I'm talking about "blocking" as in "suspending execution of a thread until a result is available".  They're very different things. :)  You can block content with your Twisted-based, proxy, but you have to do so without suspending execution to wait for results.